# How to arrange categories on y axis based on values in descending order on x axis in Python plotly express?

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to **arrange categories in descending order** on `y axis` based on `Max` values from `x axis` in `plotly express` **scatter** plot and unable to do it.

Data:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/Party_Criminal_Records/main/For_Analysis_in_R.csv')
```

Failed Attempts:

```
px.scatter(df,x = 'Criminal_Case', y = 'Party').update_layout(height = 1000).update_yaxes(type='category')
```

```
px.scatter(df,x = 'Criminal_Case', y = 'Party').update_layout(height = 1100).update_yaxes(categoryorder='category ascending')
```

```
px.box(df,x = 'Criminal_Case', y = 'Party').update_layout(height = 1000).update_yaxes(categoryorder='total ascending')
```

How can I arrange **categories** in `Python Plotly Express` ?

I was able to do this in `R` and desired result is shown below:

`R` code that worked:`df %>%  ggplot(aes(x = Criminal_Case, y = fct_reorder(Party, Criminal_Case, .fun = max) )) + geom_point()`

Expected output using R:
[image: Desired order of Plot built using R]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `update_yaxes` pass `categoryorder='max ascending'`

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/Party_Criminal_Records/main/For_Analysis_in_R.csv')

fig = px.scatter(df,x = 'Criminal_Case', y = 'Party')
fig.update_layout(height = 1000)
fig.update_yaxes(type='category', categoryorder='max ascending')
fig.show()
```

https://plotly.com/python/categorical-axes/